# Changing the format of BLOB storage in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

How to change the storage format of the BLOB. For me it is always storing AVRO file. I wanted to change as JSON format.

Also, I am seeing the following error msg in BLOB storage :

1. `avro may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension.`(Pls refer the error in the attached msg)
2. Also I am seeing encrypted msg, due to all this reason data explorer could not pull the data.

I am not able to pull the data in to data explorer because of this format issues

[image]

Comment: If it's blob storage, you uploaded/created the file as an avro file. The platform provides storage and can't change file formats for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. as per our source they have mentioned they are  sending the data as string to eventhub. but I don't know why its saving as avro? from where can I see the properties that are defined to save as avro? is there a way to find it. Pls let me know. thank you

Comment: That's a LOT of information you're missing from the question text :). I'd recommend updating the question including what you're trying to do with event hub.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you might have enabled [capturing of events streaming through Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal).

Azure Event Hubs Capture enables you to automatically deliver the streaming data in Event Hubs to an Azure Blob storage or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 or Gen 2 account of your choice.

Captured data is written in **Apache Avro** format: a compact, fast, binary format that provides rich data structures with inline schema. This format is widely used in the Hadoop ecosystem, Stream Analytics, and Azure Data Factory.

More information about working with Avro files is available in this article: [Exploring the captured files and working with Avro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#exploring-the-captured-files-and-working-with-avro)

@mmking is right in that you cannot change/convert the file formats within Azure Blob Storage, although you can [use Avro Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#use-avro-tools) to convert the file to JSON format and perform other processing.